# Flexible Team Orienteering Problem

Tags: np-complete, traveling-salesman

In Team Orienteering Problem `(TOP)` we have a graph $G=(V,E)$ and $K$ participants, We are supposed to find $K$ paths with total edge cost less than a threshold while maximising total vertex rewards. The constraint on reward collecting is once a reward has been collected by some participant the it can not be collected again by another participant. e.g. each vertex have only one piece of reward.

[image]

But given a graph like this, and two participants, where $s,t$ are the start and terminating points. I want to have two pieces of reward in $d$ but only one piece of reward in $b$ and $c$.

Does this problem has a name ? Is that proven to be NP-Complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it has a name but it's **NP**-hard. Just take $K=1$, give every edge and vertex weight $1$ and ask if there's a solution with vertex reward $|V|$ and edge cost at most $|V|-1$. This happens if, and only if, there's an $s$–$t$ Hamiltonian path.  The decision version "Can I get reward at least $R$ with cost at most $C$" is **NP**-complete.

Comment: I understand if $n=\vert V \vert$ it will end up creating a hamiltonian path. But having more than 2 reward points in the same vertex doesn't play any role with one participant only. if $K\geq 1$ we cannot use all $\vert V \vert$ vertices because of the vertex sharing coefficient (limited number of rewards in each vertex).

Comment: @NeelBasu Setting $K=1$ allows us to solve an **NP**-hard problem, so this problem is **NP**-hard. It doesn't matter what happens when $K=2$, because $K=1$ on its own has that power.

Comment: Thanks, understood. However if I asked for miximizing `(total rewards - total edge cost)` with limited rewards on vertices would that still be NP-complete with $K\geq 2$ ? I think in that case $K$ matters.

Comment: Well, you can even ask if the original problem is still **NP**-hard if restricted to $K>1$. My guess is that it probably is, but a reduction doesn't immediately come to mind. Maybe you could do something with max-cut? Reward-minus-cost shouldn't make much difference, since you can always give every vertex weight 2 and every edge weight 1 and you're in the same situation of having to construct a Hamilton path when $K=1$.

Comment: Yes I was trying to reduce it for two days. I am afraid that people may think reward-cost is solvable by shortest path, but that sharing makes it hard. Now I think TOP is not the best problem to reduce, I was thinking Graph partitioning is something to start with. I will try with Max cut.  Here is the question I posted for that https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86785/shortest-path-like-objective-with-team-orienteering-problem

Comment: Looks like Steiner Tree problem as well

Comment: Shortest path? I’d assumed “miximizing” was a typo for max rather than min?

Comment: The objective function looks similar to that of shortest path. Thats why I put the title that way.

Comment: I see your point now. Anyway, yes, the problem looks more complicated and interesting if you insist on $K>1$. I suggest posting a new question to ask about that case. I don't know the answers but I'd be interested to see if anyone else does!

Comment: Possibly This is more like Max-Flow-Min Cut with capacities on vertices instead of capacities on edges.  But that will be very complicated title. Also I don't know whether it is possible to make Edmomds-Karp work with capacitated vertex, This is the new question. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86785/shortest-path-like-objective-with-team-orienteering-problem